# sklearn SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to split my dataset using sklearn. However, I am getting a syntax error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import cross_validation
X_train, X-test, y_train, y_test=cross_validation.train_test_Split(X_features,y_target,test_size=0.4,random_state=0)
```

Error:

> ```
> File "<ipython-input-16-0e0c9ad420f6>", line 4
>             X_train, X-test, y_train, y_test=cross_validation.train_test_Split(X_features,y_target,test_size=0.4,random_state=0)
>
> ^
> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
> ```

Comment: You have a typo: it should be `cross_validation.train_test_split` (i.e. lowercase `s` in `split`)

Comment: `-` is only a operator and therefore `X-test` is an invalid variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full **correct** version is the following.

The one that @Pradeep proposed will give an error since there is no `train_test_Split` but `train_test_split` with lowercase `s`.

In your code you **have 2 mistakes**: **1) the uppercase `s` and 2 ) `X-test` will be recognized as the subtraction operation.**

---

**Use this:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import cross_validation

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=cross_validation.train_test_split(X_features,y_target,test_size=0.4,random_state=0)
```

Comment: Consider upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can not use '-' for a variable name here. that's an operator in python. 
Change it to X_test

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=cross_validation.train_test_Split(X_features,y_target,test_size=0.4,random_state=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

I tried this and it worked for me, like a charm !!